# hadoop filtering map output

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a use case where in certain keys that map phase generates need to be filtered out before the reduce kicks in. Is something like this doable? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the Mapper Class to filter the input  will be more accurate , 
because , the execution of combiner is not guaranteed, Hadoop may or may not execute a combiner. Also, if required it may execute it more then 1 times. Therefore your MapReduce jobs should not depend on the combiners execution.

Comment: I'm using TextInputFormat in my mapper which reads one line at a time. I want to flag a file if some pattern is found even in one of the lines...however because all the map tasks run in parallel, there is no way for me to know if a particular file is "flagged" until all the lines are scanned. This is where I'm stuck on.

Comment: Your points on using combiners is why I didn't mention those in my answer.  I suppose I should have stated that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options that come to mind:

- Modify your mapper to not output the values you want to filter
- Write a reducer that filters out the values you don't want, and feed the output of that reducer to another MapReduce job

Using a combiner is not a good choice for this task because, as @100gods mentions, combiner execution is not guaranteed.

Comment: He could also use Combiners to filter out the values if he can't change the code of the mapper.

Comment: Thank you both ! Combiners seem to be the better option as I can't change the mapper code.

Comment: Combiner? well the option is not correct. There is no guarantee that the combiner code would execute. The best choice would be "Not to emit the key value pair that you need to filter off", as mentioned above.